# How does a multi-class SVC with ovo models make a prediction if there is a "tie" in votes?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Let's say I have a multi-class set of data with 4 labels: `[A, B, C, D]` that I want to use an ovo SVC classifier to predict. I know that once I train, I'll have 6 ovo models trained and can use
`svc.decision_function()` to see the set of decision function outputs. Those functions are organized as

```
[AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD]
```

with the first letter being the positive case, and the second letter being the negative case. As I understand it, prediction takes these decision function scores and produces a set of "votes", the mode of which is the final prediction. Something like:

```
[AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD] #Model Organization
[1.4, 0.2, 0.6, 3, -2.2, -0.4] #Decision function output
[A, A, A, B, D, D] #Prediction for each model
```

The mode is A, so the `svc.predict()` function should output `A`. My question is what if the decision function output looks like this instead (I just flipped the sign of the 2nd entry but pretend its a new output):

```
[AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD] #Model Organization
[1.4, -0.2, 0.5, 3, -2.2, -0.4] #Decision function output
[A, C, A, B, D, D] #Prediction for each model
```

Now both `A` or `D` are the mode, so how would SVC break the tie and make the prediction? Speculatively I would sum the values of the decision function output (wrt the direction of the label) for each label, since the distance from the decision surface indicates to me how decisively the model predicted the label in each case. That would make `D` in the example. But I could also see using the specific score for the "AD" model. Regardless, not sure how SVC does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It breaks ties for the lowest-value class.  It's hard to track that down, because it appears to be happening at the level of `libsvm` rather than at the `sklearn` level. Luckily, [an example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_tie_breaking.html) arising from an [earlier issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8276) provides a dataset where we can see the action.  Here's the original (the plot looks the same after changing `decision_function_shape` to `ovo`):

[image: three-class SVM example]

The middle triangular region gets classified along with the lower-left region, which is class 0.  The decisions of the ovo models are tied with one vote for each class in that region.

Swapping the names of class 0 and 2 (e.g. by taking `y=2-y`) produces:

[image: new SVM results]

The triangular region is now classified along with the top-left region, which is newly named as zero.

Comment: Thanks, that's very clear & interesting. So my example would probably be 'A' then, thinking alphabetically. Reading about the `break_ties` parameter, it seems to be computationally expensive. So I guess the thinking is pragmatic in that its unlikely a dataset would have enough cases that a) are tied, and b) have the same lower value class (AC tied vs BC tied) to really affect your model.